# How can I can check if a value exists in an ArrayList?

Tags: java

```
try {                   
    List<UpdateStockModel> 
    stockistIds=updateStockMapper.getStockInvoiceId(stockmodel);
    String myList = new String();
    for (UpdateStockModel x : stockistIds) {
        //System.out.println("stockist list id.." + x.getStockInvoiceIds());    

        myList = myList.concat(x.getStockInvoiceIds());
        myList = myList.concat(",");

    }   

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(myList);   
    System.out.println("list.." + list);    
    System.out.println("stockInvoiceId is.." + 
    stockmodel.getStockInvoiceIds());
    System.out.println("list status.." +list.contains(stockmodel.getStockInvoiceIds()));
    if (list.contains(stockmodel.getStockInvoiceIds()) ==true){         
        return true;    
    } else {
        return true;           
    }
}
```

Output:

```
list..[47,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,62,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,74,75,]

stockInvoiceId is..66

list status..false

return else
```

Here 66 existed in list but return false.I need to get true

Comment: It would help if you'd at least know how to add an element to a list, and what the difference is between a list and a string

Comment: Not possible that you get a result of `false`. Both branches in your `if-else` statement return `true`.

Comment: *"Here 66 existed in list but return false"* No. Your list contains only one element, and it's that ugly concatenated string you created before. `66` is not an element in your list. But even given that, your logic will still return `true`, as per my previous comment.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen ...sorry by mistake it will post both are true..                                                                                if (list.contains(stockmodel.getStockInvoiceIds()) ==true){         
        return true;    
    } else {
        return false;           
    }

Comment: Maybe `return list.contains(stockmodel.getStockInvoiceIds())` is more understandable rather than the `if-else`

Answer (score 3):

Okay lets get it straight here.
You got a List full of objects which contain a ID.
You get the IDs from the object and concate them to a single large String.
Later on you add this single String to an ArrayList and expect the `List.contains()` method to find a proper match for you. This is **not** how it works.

You can either fix this, by calling `list.get(0).contains(...)` which will work since you will retrieve your string from the list and check it for the ID or even better,you add the Strings themself to an ArrayList.

Doing so would end up similiar to this:

```
 List<UpdateStockModel> 
    stockistIds=updateStockMapper.getStockInvoiceId(stockmodel);
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (UpdateStockModel x : stockistIds) { 
        myList.add(x.getStockInvoiceIds()); 
    }
```

Doing so will replace the following part:

```
//This all becomes useless since you will already have a list with proper objects. 
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(myList);   
    System.out.println("list.." + list);    
    System.out.println("stockInvoiceId is.." + 
    stockmodel.getStockInvoiceIds());
    System.out.println("list status.." +list.contains(stockmodel.getStockInvoiceIds()));
```

It's not rocket science.

Think of Lists as they were just more dynamic and flexible Arrays.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're after:

```
Set<String> ids = updateStockMapper.getStockInvoiceId(stockmodel)
        .stream()
        .map(usm -> usm.getStockInvoiceIds())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
String id = stockmodel.getStockInvoiceIds();

return ids.contains(id);
```

Comment: Neat solution using Java 8 streams. Might be a little to complex for OP tho.

Comment: @L.Spillner Maybe OP can revisit in a couple of years :) I won't bother with a Java 7-ish version. You pretty much laid it out in your answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try to initalize the list as follows:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (UpdateStockModel x : stockistIds) {
    //System.out.println("stockist list id.." + x.getStockInvoiceIds());    
    list.add(x.getStockInvoiceIds());
}
```

Then you can compare agains a list and not against a String.

Answer (score 0):

```
// if the element that you want to check is of string type

    String value= "66";// you use element instead of 66
Boolean flag=false;
    if (list.contains(value)){         
        flag=true;    
    } else {
        flag=false;           
    }

//you can use flag where you want
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? If you get to the point where you're introducing meaningless variables named `flag`, you know there's something seriously wrong with the design of your code.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you setup the list varible as as an Arry with one entry.

replacing the statement

```
list.contains(..)
```

with

```
stockistIds.contains(..)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: The types do not match. `stockistIds` is a list of `UpdateStockModel` objects, while `stockmodel.getStockInvoiceIds()` returns a string.

Answer (score -4):

The problem is in the `if` statement
Change:

```
if (list.contains(stockmodel.getStockInvoiceIds()) ==true){         
        return true;    
    } else {
        return true;           
    }
```

to:

```
if (list.contains(stockmodel.getStockInvoiceIds()) ==true){         
        return true;    
    } else {
        return false;           
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to find the differences between the two code blocks, but I cannot!

Comment: The actual problem is the way the list is constructed

Comment: @JorgeHortelano in the 2nd statement the 2nd return is set to `false` instead of `true`. Which still does not fix the problem at all.

Comment: You could at least have changed the code's indentation to make it look like you've changed something.

Comment: @L.Spillner ahhhh. good catch. makes the answer even worse though... :D

Comment: @L.Spillner. Thanks, I am getting older and seems I have issues for reading.

Comment: @JorgeHortelano No Problem, it took me some time as well. To be honest i did not even notice that both cases returned `true` in the original code and i first became aware of that thanks to this answer.